# Remove html formatting "&gt;" from text file using Python csv.reader

Tags: python, html, regex, file, csv

I have a text file with ; used as the delimiter. The problem is that it has some html text formatting in it such as `&gt;` Obviously the ; in this causes problems. 
The text file is large and I don't have a list of these html strings, that is there are many different examples such as `$amp;`. How can I remove all of them using python.
The file is a list of names, addresses, phone number and a few more fields. I am looking for the crap.html.remove(textfile) module

Comment: It will mostly just consist of &amp; , &lt; , &gt; . Won't just find and replace suffice? Maybe you can create a list of tuples http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html and use a lambda function to find replace it in your file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quickest way is probably to use the undocumented but so far stable `unescape` method in [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html):

```
import HTMLParser
s= HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(s)
```

Note this will necessarily output a Unicode string, so if you have any non-ASCII bytes in there you will need to `s.decode(encoding)` first.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the code from [here](http://effbot.org/zone/re-sub.htm#unescape-html):

```
import re, htmlentitydefs

##
# Removes HTML or XML character references and entities from a text string.
#
# @param text The HTML (or XML) source text.
# @return The plain text, as a Unicode string, if necessary.

def unescape(text):
    def fixup(m):
        text = m.group(0)
        if text[:2] == "&#":
            # character reference
            try:
                if text[:3] == "&#x":
                    return unichr(int(text[3:-1], 16))
                else:
                    return unichr(int(text[2:-1]))
            except (ValueError, OverflowError):
                pass
        else:
            # named entity
            try:
                text = unichr(htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint[text[1:-1]])
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return text # leave as is
    return re.sub("&#?\w+;", fixup, text)
```

Of course, this only takes care of HTML entities. You may have other semicolons in the text that mess with your CSV parser. But I guess you already know that...

**UPDATE**: added catch for possible `OverflowError`.

Comment: I get an error
/Users/vmd/Dropbox/Marketing Material/Leads/formatleaddata.py in removehtml(text)
     40                                 pass
     41                 return text # leave as is
---> 42         return re.sub("&#?\w+;", fixup, text) 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/5.1.0/lib/python2.5/re.pyc in sub(pattern, repl, string, count)
    148     if a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    149     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 150     return _compile(pattern, 0).sub(repl, string, count)
    152 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0):

Comment: That is quite a mouthful, and it's not clear to me what the error is. Do you have an exception type? Maybe you should try posting your exception details in a separate answer, just so we can have proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

On most Unix systems (including your Mac OS X), you can recode the input text file with:

```
recode html.. file_with_html.txt
```

This replaces &gt; by ">", etc.

You can call this through Python's subprocess module, for instance.